# Add navigation menu beside the logo in the header magento 2

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I use Magento2 with sample data Luma theme and I applied a new custom theme 
Now I need to know the right way to add the navigation menu inside the header I want it between the logo and search box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

You can move navigation menu using move element

add below lines to **default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout  /etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works correct. Even this one did not break the mobile navigation and add after the logo.

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

Comment: Works. Tested on 2.4.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in `default.xml` layout file of your custom theme.

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.panel"/>
```